# Can Loopback IP be Public

Tags: routing, loopback, public

I have a Usecase where an Access Device need to reach a Core Device over the Internet. Access Device is configured with the Public IP of the Core device as of now so that it can reach the Core over the Internet.

[Click here for current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m61YV.png)

However, we want to add another Public Interface via another ISP for Redundancy on the Core Device. The application that resides on the Core Device can only bind to one IP Address which means I have to use a loopback IP Address and have the two Physical Interfaces configured with Public IP1(ISP1) and Public IP2(IP2).

[Click here to see i would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m61YV.png)

If my Access Device need to access the Application which is bound to a loopback IP, the loopback IP need to be a Public IP as well right? Is it possible to have a Public IP for a Loopback that's reachable via ISP1 and ISP2?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a X/Y question? What are you attempting to achieve? What is the application? Why isn't two IP's an alternative? Is it possible to place a router in front that can handle the redundancy?

Comment: Vidarlo, Application can only be bound to a single IP. Application Support team gave me this suggestion of having 2 physical interfaces with a loopback ip bound to the application. But I dont understand how we can configure a Public IP as Loopback as they suggested